# GVIM. How to change certain words that match the pattern?

Tags: vim, replace

In normal mode I press +* and VIM highlighs the occurences of the word under cursor. How to change for example 2,4-5 (second, fourth and fifth) words in search results with %s command?
I know I can use %s and to change the searched word in certain lines, but it is not what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you did a find first, you could use

```
:%s//replaced/gic
```

It will ask for each replacement if it needs to be done.